# Edit audio from Final Cut Pro X 10.4.5 in Logic Pro X 10.4.4

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I'm new to Logic Pro, more experienced with FCP. I have a video project in FCP with may different sound situations, and I need to level the audio. I've tried to do this in FCP, and that works reasonably well, but now I have Logic Pro, I hope to have a better tool available.

[image: Logic Pro X Import Menu]

I've tried to export to XML in FCP, but can't open or import that in LP. I read somewhere that you need to publish from FCP to LP, but I don't see that option and have no idea how to do that. What I found online was for older versions - no idea if that is the problem here.

How can I edit audio from a Final Cut Pro X (10.4.5) project in Logic Pro X (10.4.4)?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to open the menu Preferences > Advanced, then select all. Then the FCP Import menu becomes available. The Help menu did help me, but could be more directly explaining that you need to set this option in the advanced preferences.

[image: Logic Pro - Import Media Files]

[image: Logic Pro X - Advanced Preferences]

[image: Logic Pro X - Import Final Cut Pro XML]

Unbelievable that they hide this import option.